# A limit of recurrence sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Given $a_1=\frac{1}{3},a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{a_n^2}{n^2}$，work out $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n}$（I think it's $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$,but I can't prove it)

Comment: Your conjecture seems to be incorrect. $a_{1000}\approx0.609476>\frac6{\pi^2}\approx0.607927$. The actual limit appears to be closer to $0.609848$.

Comment: It's possible to prove that the limit exists. But I don't know whether the limit can be computed. How do we know that the limit can be computed analytically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the existence of limit of $x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{x_n^2}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672888/prove-the-existence-of-limit-of-x-n1-x-n-fracx-n2n2)